# Find the limit of a sequence defined by $x_n =\sqrt{n^2+1}-n, n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to use the standard definition $x_n \rightarrow x$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|x_N-x|<\epsilon$.

So my claim is $x_n\rightarrow 0$ If I set $N=\epsilon^2,$ then the following expression  $|\sqrt{n^2+1}-n-0|<\epsilon$  will hold true. I solved for $N$ by squaring both sides $n^2+1-n^2<\epsilon^2$ Does this work?

Edit: Made a dumb algebraic mistake, thanks everyone.

Comment: $(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)^2=n^2+1-2n\sqrt{n^2+1}+n^2\neq n^2+1-n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n=\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}<\frac{1}{n}$$

So you have $|x_n|<\varepsilon$ when $\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so do we say for $n\ge N $ where $ N>1/\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** We have
$$x_n = \sqrt{n^2+1} - n \implies x_n = \dfrac1{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} < \dfrac1{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that for positive $n$ we have
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2\gt n^2+1.$$
It follows that
$$n\lt \sqrt{n^2+1}\lt n+\frac{1}{2n},$$
and therefore
$$0\lt \sqrt{n^2+1}-n\lt \frac{1}{2n}.$$
We conclude by Squeezing that our limit is $0$.